# flot pie chart tooltip percentage

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

I have having a problem with flot pie chart, its not showing correct percent value in tooltip, for example it shows `series1:%p.0%`

**js code**

```
  var data = [{
    label: "Series 0",
    data: 1
}, {
    label: "Series 1",
    data: 3
}, {
    label: "Series 2",
    data: 9
}, {
    label: "Series 3",
    data: 20
}];
var plotObj = $.plot($("#flot-pie-chart"), data, {
    series: {
        pie: {
            show: true
        }
    },
    grid: {
        hoverable: true
    },
    colors: ["#99c7ce","#efb3e6","#a48ad4","#AEC785","#fdd752"],
    tooltip: true,
    tooltipOpts: {
        content: "%p.0%, %s", // show percentages, rounding to 2 decimal places
        shifts: {
            x: 20,
            y: 0
        },
        defaultTheme: false
    }
});
```

Please help to resolve this.

thanks

Comment: I created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a7zc4/) with your data and options, and it seems to work -- for example on hover the tooltip displays `9%, Series 1`

Comment: @prmech yes correct, this code is working in jsfiddle but not at my page.

Comment: You'll need to edit your question and add more code detail. Which jQuery/flot libraries are you using, what order you are including them, etc.

Comment: Are you using the latest version of Flot and the tooltip plugin?

Answer (score 1):

You Need to include `jquery.flot.tooltip.min.js`and change few setting as per below working example to display the tooltip with value.

```js
datapie = [
    {label: "Running",  data: 19.5, color: '#e1ab0b'},
    {label: "Stopped",  data: 4.5, color: '#fe0000'},
    {label: "Terminated",  data: 36.6, color: '#93b40f'}
];

function legendFormatter(label, series) {
    return '<div ' + 
           'style="font-size:8pt;text-align:center;padding:2px;">' +
           label + ' ' + Math.round(series.percent)+'%</div>';
};

$.plot($("#placeholder"), datapie, {
 
 series: {
     pie: {show: true, threshold: 0.1,
        // label: {show: true}
    }
    },
     grid: {
        hoverable: true
    },
    tooltip: true,
    tooltipOpts: {
        cssClass: "flotTip",
        content: "%p.0%, %s",
        shifts: {
            x: 20,
            y: 0
        },
        defaultTheme: false
    },
   
    
    legend: {show: true, labelFormatter: legendFormatter}
    
    });
```

```css
#flotTip {
    padding: 3px 5px;
    background-color: #000;
    z-index: 100;
    color: #fff;
    opacity: .80;
    filter: alpha(opacity=85);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://envato.stammtec.de/themeforest/melon/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://envato.stammtec.de/themeforest/melon/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.pie.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://envato.stammtec.de/themeforest/melon/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.tooltip.min.js"></script>

<div id="placeholder" style="width:500px;height:400px;"></div>
```

Working Example Link : http://jsfiddle.net/Rnusy/335/

Comment: Would it be possible to display the row data (19.5 4.5 36.6) in the tooltip instead of percentage? Tried %x and %y but both does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You need the Tooltip plugin.
See a complete list of available plugins here: [Flot plugins](http://www.flotcharts.org/plugins/)